# Find element that has unknown namespace in lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an XML with many levels. Each level may have namespace attached to it. I want to `find` a specific element whose name I know, but not its namespace. For example:

`my_file.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:ddd:eee">
  <country name="Liechtenstein" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
  </country>
  <country name="Singapore" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
  </country>
  <country name="Panama" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:panama:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
  </country>
</data>
```

```
import lxml.etree as etree

tree = etree.parse('my_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

cntry_node = root.find('.//country')
```

The `find` above does not return anything to `cntry_node`. In my real data, the levels are deeper than this example. The lxml document talks about namespace. When I do this:

```
root.nsmap
```

I see this:

```
{None: 'aaa:bbb:ccc:ddd:eee'}
```

If someone could explain how to access the full `nsmap` and/or how to use it to `find` a specific element? Thanks very much.

Comment: @MathiasMüller @mzjn Maybe I still don't understand the namespace concept here. I presume when parsing an XML file, the namespace is stored in ```nsmap```. Hence, we can access it. From the answers here, it seems I have to define this file manually? Which is a massive amount of work for a large XML file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could declare all namespaces, but given the structure of your sample xml, I would argue you are better off disregarding namespaces altogether and just using `local-name()`; so

```
cntry_node = root.xpath('.//*[local-name()="country"]')
cntry_node
```

returns

```
[<Element {aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee}country at 0x1cddf1d4680>,
 <Element {aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee}country at 0x1cddf1d47c0>,
 <Element {aaa:bbb:ccc:panama:eee}country at 0x1cddf1d45c0>]
```

Comment: Nice answer! It does not address the OP's confusion about nsmap though. You could add [some comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67492642/find-element-that-has-unknown-namespace-in-lxml#comment119295075_67492642) [about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67492642/find-element-that-has-unknown-namespace-in-lxml#comment119295166_67492642).

Comment: Thanks again for helping !

Comment: @TristanTran Glad it helped!

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `{*}` as the namespace wildcard...

```py
cntry_node = root.find('.//{*}country')
```

Note: This only works with `find()`, `findall()`, `iter()`, etc.; not `xpath()`.

[See here](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful !

Answer (score 3):

**`nsmap` is not a global collection of all namespaces of an XML document**

I believe your impression was that `nsmap` is a collection of *all* namespaces that are present in an XML document. And that this collection would be available after parsing the document. That is not the case.

`nsmap` gives you access to the namespace definitions of one element only. So this:

```
root = tree.getroot()
root.nsmap
```

Gives you the namespace definitions known in the context of the `root` element. Keep in mind that "root" is just the name of a Python variable and in fact contains the outermost element of your XML document (I know this because you called `getroot()`). The outermost element of your document is:

```
<data xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:ddd:eee">
```

so it is expected that its nsmap would contain

```
{None: 'aaa:bbb:ccc:ddd:eee'}
```

(The nsmap has `None` in it because this is a default namespace without a namespace prefix that would go where the `None` is.)

**XML document has a terrible structure**

Usually, the best way to deal with namespaces is to define them yourself (without taking them from the input document). Suppose we would like to find the following element:

```
<country name="Liechtenstein" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee">
```

This `country` element is in the *default namespace* with the namespace URI "aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee". To find it with lxml, define a mapping:

```
my_own_namespace_mapping = {'prefix': 'aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee'}
```

and then use it when retrieving nodes:

```
root.xpath('.//prefix:country', namespaces=my_own_namespace_mapping)
[<Element {aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee}country at 0x7fea87f363f8>]
```

However, in the case of your input document it appears you would need to do that separately for each `country` element because they are each in their own default namespace:

```
root.xpath('.//prefix:country', namespaces={'prefix': 'aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee'})
[<Element {aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee}country at 0x7fea879cfd40>]
```

and so on. That is very impractical, not because lxml or namespaces are complicated, but because someone designed this XML format badly.

---

By the way, once you found one of those elements you can use `nsmap` again to test if what I say above is true:

```
root.xpath('.//prefix:country', namespaces={'prefix': 'aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee'})[0].nsmap
{None: 'aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee'}
```

Comment: Thanks. This clears it up a lot. I wish some details like this were included in the ```lxml``` documentation.

Comment: Muller I just experimented something and updated my question. Wondering if you could take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @TristanTran Updating your question can be confusing, considering that you already accepted an answer which might not fit anymore, and the question does not have a clear focus anymore. Instead of updating your question, please consider asking a new one (you can link to it here). Thanks!